# How to fill whole wave curve shape with color using Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am new to Illustrator. I can't fill the curve shape with color in Illustrator. 
I want to fill the whole curve shape with the color. How can I do this?

I want to fill this whole curve with blue shade.

[image]

Comment: Close the path.

Comment: How can you show with an example I am new in this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Scott has suggested in his comment, close the path to create a completely enclosed shape, using the Pen Tool. Holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> as you click and drag constrains the angles to horizontal and vertical. Enabling Smart Guides allows you to line everything up.

[image]

Comment: Worked! Thank you.